# Existence of prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ an odd prime number and $r_p$ the smallest positive primary root of $p$. I want to show that for each natural number $N$ there are infinite prime numbers $p$ for which $N<r_p<p-N$.

I have thought the following:

An integer $a$, with $(a,n)=1$ is called primary root modulo $n$, if $ord_n(a)=\phi(n)$.

So in our case we have $ord_p(r_p)=\phi(p)=p-1$.

But does this help somehow to get the desired inequality?

Comment: If all the numbers $1,2,\dots,N-1$ are, say, quadratic residues modulo $p$, then they can't be primitive roots. And if $p\equiv1\bmod4$, then $k$ is a quadratic residue if and only if $p-k$ is.

Comment: So, do you see how to proceed now?